# I have defined a function with two outputs and returns a list. how can I call for one of the outputs in the minimize function?

Tags: python, list, function

how can I call for one veriable returned by a function out of multiple outputs to use it in other function

solution = minimize(objective,...)
I defined objective two return a list of two variables not one.
If it is defined to return one value the code runs smoothly otherwise it won't

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post any comments because of reputation, but does the `objective` function needs to strictly return two values? Anyway, you can take the value that you want just like from a list:

```py
solution = minimize(objective()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite appearances, a Python function cannot return two values. If this line is executed in a function,

```
return 1, 2
```

then one tuple `(1, 2)` is returned. That tuple contains two values, but just one value is returned, namely the tuple.

If you want only the first of those values, index the returned tuple. In your case, if you want only the first value in the tuple returned from your `objective` function then use

```
solution = minimize(objective(parameters)[0], moreparameters)
```

or if you want the second value in the tuple,

```
solution = minimize(objective(parameters)[1], moreparameters)
```

If the `objective` function has no parameters, then the line looks like

```
solution = minimize(objective()[0], moreparameters)
```